# Rewriting Curl request in Python: Result Invalid Json

Tags: python, curl

I have this curl that works, it returns this

```
curl -X POST \
https://login.smoobu.com/booking/checkApartmentAvailability \
-H 'Api-Key: xxxxx' \
-H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
-d '{
    "arrivalDate" : "2018-04-01",
    "departureDate":  "2019-12-03",
    "apartments": [126936, 127858, 126937],
    "customerId": 38484
}'
```

it returns this

```
{
    "availableApartments": [
        127858
    ],
    "prices": [],
    "errorMessages": {
        "126936": {
            "errorCode": 405,
            "message": "The chosen day of departure is not available.",
            "departureDays": [
                "Sa"
            ]
        },
        "126937": {
            "errorCode": 405,
            "message": "The chosen day of departure is not available.",
            "departureDays": [
                "Sa"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I rewrote it in python like so

```
In [1]: import requests

In [2]: headers = {'Api-Key': 'xxxx', 'cache-control': 'no-cache'}

In [8]: payload = {
...:     "arrivalDate" : "2018-04-01",
...:     "departureDate":  "2019-12-03",
...:     "apartments": [126936, 127858, 126937],
...:     "customerId": 38484
...: }

In [4]: r = requests.post("https://login.smoobu.com/booking/checkApartmentAvailability", data=payload, headers=headers)

In [5]: r
Out[5]: <Response [400]>

In [13]: r.content
Out[13]: b'{"title":"Error occurred","detail":"json is invalid"}'
```

I got back a response of invalid json, I'm not sure why though since the way I know it works is it takes a dict and turns it into a json request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For sending `JSON`, you should use the `json` parameter:

```py
r = requests.post("https://login.smoobu.com/booking/checkApartmentAvailability", json=payload, headers=headers)
```

As explained in the [docs](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/):

```py
r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload))
r = requests.post(url, json=payload)
```

> Instead of encoding the dict yourself, you can also pass it directly using the json parameter (added in version 2.4.2) and it will be encoded automatically

Comment: makes sense, so the other way it sent as a basic post string request. It works btw.